# Two ways of optimize the same function

Tags: logistic, deep-learning, theano

i m reading actually this tutorial about deepLearning and in particurlar about Logistic Regression.

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg

I don't get why it first says to optimize logistic regression taking the max Probability and after using the Log loss function ?

Sorry you can explain me the point where him will use the Argmax and where Will use the Loss ?

you would not need only 1 of this 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but the short answer is that the argmax is not involved in optimizing the function.

The idea is that $p(y \vert x)$ contains the probability of an item (or rather, a minibatch of items) being assigned to each of the possible classes. If you want to make a *prediction*, you would choose the class with the highest probability, as in:

```
self.y_pred = T.argmax(self.p_y_given_x, axis=1)
```

On the other hand, to update the model parameters, the example is performing stochastic gradient descent on the log loss, which effectively tries to maximize the probability of the true label for each item. This is defined in the function:

```
def negative_log_likelihood(self, y):
    return -T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

where y is used to select the probability of the true label for each item from p_y_given_x.

It may look to you like the argmax is being computed before the log likelihood, but this is not the case. The key thing to understand is that the lines above are defining operations on symbolic variables in theano, and they will not be actually used until needed. In this case, the optimization for a minibatch happens when the train_model function is called:

```
minibatch_avg_cost = train_model(minibatch_index)
```

train_model is a theano function, defined as:

```
train_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    updates=updates,
    givens={
        x: train_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: train_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

This definition tells you that when it is called, it will update the parameters according to:

```
updates = [(classifier.W, classifier.W - learning_rate * g_W),
           (classifier.b, classifier.b - learning_rate * g_b)]
```

classifier.W and classifier.b are the relevant model parameters. g_W and g_b in turn are gradients which are computed automatically by the lines:

```
g_W = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.W)
g_b = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.b)
```

Finally, these gradients are computed using the cost function:

```
cost = classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)
```

which is the symbolic operation defined above. In other words, the argmax is not used in updating the model parameters. That argmax function is only called when the model needs to make a prediction, as in the predict_model function or the errors function, which compares $y$ to $\hat y$.

Comment: Welcome Dallas. I have edited your post to display some of the math as math. You should check that I have not introduced any errors.

Comment: actually after you learn the parameters you should have an equation  y = parameters * variabiles + b. after you have calculated the parameters, you should have to substitute just the variabiles of the New sample , multiply and have as result Y .   Now at this point why you need Argmax ? i dont get it !

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your confusion. Are you talking about the line "self.p_y_given_x = T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, self.W) + self.b)".  As I explained above, this computes the probability of x being assigned to each of the classes. Remember, though, that this is multi-class classification, so there 10 possible classes (the 10 digits in MNIST). You would need to take the argmax in order to determine which of the 10 classes has the highest probability. If I am still misunderstanding your question, perhaps you could point to a specific part of the code that is confusing you?

Comment: @DallasCard my point is very simple ... T.nnet.softmax(T.dot(input, self.W) + self.b)  learn for you W and b is this correct? after you do... x*W(matrix) + b = vector Y . Vector Y is already the result of the prediction right?

Comment: @T-student No. Remember, this is classification, not regression. b is a vector. x*W + b would give you a vector of unnormalized scores for each class (of which there are 10 in this example, one for each of the 10 digits). To make a prediction you would choose the class with the highest score.

Comment: ok i understand